# How do I get the classOf a ClassTag?

Tags: scala, reflection

This doesn't work - is there any way I can keep my code generified and somehow reflect the classOf a ClassTag??

```
class Foo[T : reflect.ClassTag] { def foo = classOf[T] }

<console>:7: error: class type required but T found
   class Foo[T : reflect.ClassTag] { def foo = classOf[T] }
```

It seems this should work but alas :(

Answer (score 34):

Yes, that's possible.

```
class Foo[T: reflect.ClassTag] {
  def ctag = implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[T]]
  def foo: Class[T] = ctag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}
```

or shorter:

```
class Foo[T](implicit ctag: reflect.ClassTag[T]) {
  def foo: Class[T] = ctag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I literally just got this as I saw your answer. Using the implicit worked beautifully.

Comment: `classTag[T].runtimeClass` is a little bit shorter

Comment: @sschaef But it returns `Class[_]` and not `Class[T]`, in case it matters.

Comment: sschaef is right. `classTag[T].runtimeClass` is a shorthand for `implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass` and thus needs an `asInstanceOf[Class[T]]` as I posted

Comment: @Klaus, is it also possible to derive the name of the class (string) from ClassTag[T] by using this approach? Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576345/scala-retrieve-class-name-from-classtag)