# Scala: Retrieve class-name from ClassTag

Tags: scala, generics

I'm writing a *generic method* that can convert `Any` type argument to the an object of passed `ClassTag[T]` type, if possible.

```
def getTypedArg[T: ClassTag](any: Any): Option[T] = {
      any match {
        case t: T => Some(t)
        case invalid =>
          logger.warn(s"Invalid argument: $invalid")
          None
      }
}
```

I want the *log message* to be more *precise* like this:

```
case invalid => logger.warn(s"Invalid argument: $invalid of type $className")
```

---

How can I retrieve `className` from the `ClassTag[T]`?

Alternatively, is there a fundamentally different approach that can serve my use-case better?

Comment: I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974706/how-do-i-get-the-classof-a-classtag) but can't figure out how to apply it to my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this import statement

```
import scala.reflect._
```

and change the logging statement as,

```
logger.warn(s"Invalid argument: $invalid of type ${classTag[T].runtimeClass}")
```

This is taken from 
[Scala classOf for type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200253/scala-classof-for-type-parameter)

Comment: That worked; I further added `getSimpleName` to convert *qualified class-name with packages* `com.company.package.A$A45$A$A45$MyClass` to *just the class-name* `MyClass`, i.e., `classTag[T].runtimeClass.getSimpleName`