# In Scala, how to cast a value when a TypeTag is available

Tags: scala, types

Given

- a value of type `Any`
- a `TypeTag` corresponding to the desired type

How can I cast the value

Unfortunately, the following snippet doesn't compile

```
val v: Any = 123
val tag    = typeTag[Int]
val i      = v.asInstanceOf[t.tpe]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of where you would want to do this? Exactly doing what you are asking is not possible in general. The alternatives depend on the situation.

Comment: @Jasper-M I've asked a more complete question that explain the use case, cf : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013149/in-scala-how-to-deal-with-heterogeneous-list-of-the-same-parameterized-type

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def getTypedArg[T: ClassTag](any: Any): Option[T] = {
      any match {
        case t: T => Some(t)
        case invalid =>
          None
      }
}
```

---

Usage

```
scala> getTypedArg[Int](5)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> getTypedArg[Int]("str")
res2: Option[Int] = None
```

---

Source: [Retrieve class-name from ClassTag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576345/scala-retrieve-class-name-from-classtag)

---

**EDIT-1**

As asked by [**@Aki**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10116037/aki), it can be made to work with `TypeTag`s too, with this hack

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def typeToClassTag[T: TypeTag]: ClassTag[T] = {
  ClassTag[T]( typeTag[T].mirror.runtimeClass( typeTag[T].tpe ) )
}

def getTypedArg2[T: TypeTag](any: Any): Option[T] = {
  implicit val c: ClassTag[T] = typeToClassTag[T]
  any match {
    case t: T => Some(t)
    case invalid =>
      None
  }
}
```

Reference: [How to get ClassTag form TypeTag, or both at same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729321/how-to-get-classtag-form-typetag-or-both-at-same-time/18730004#18730004)

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own method that does the casting.
(note that this method will never throw ClassCastExceptions)

```
def cast[A](a: Any, tag: TypeTag[A]): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
```