# In Scala, how to deal with heterogeneous list of the same parameterized type

Tags: scala

I have an array of `Any` (in real life, it's a Spark `Row`, but it's sufficient to isolate the problem)

```
object Row {
  val buffer : Array[Any] = Array(42, 21, true)
}
```

And I want to apply some operations on its elements.
So, I've defined a simple ADT to define a `compute` operation on a type `A`

```
  trait Op[A] {
    def cast(a: Any) : A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
    def compute(a: A) : A
  }

  case object Count extends Op[Int] {
    override def compute(a: Int): Int = a + 1
  }

  case object Exist extends Op[Boolean] {
    override def compute(a: Boolean): Boolean = a
  }
```

Given that I have a list of all operations and I know which operation is to apply to each element, let's use these operations.

```
object GenericsOp {
  import Row._

  val ops = Seq(Count, Exist)

  def compute() = {
    buffer(0) = ops(0).compute(ops(0).cast(buffer(0)))
    buffer(1) = ops(0).compute(ops(0).cast(buffer(1)))
    buffer(2) = ops(1).compute(ops(1).cast(buffer(2)))
  }
}
```

By design, for a given op, types are aligned between `cast` and `combine`. But unfortunately the following code does not compile. The error is

```
Type mismatch, expected: _$1, actual: AnyVal
```

Is there a way to make it work ?

I've found a workaround by using abstract type member instead of type parameter.

```
object AbstractOp extends App {
  import Row._

  trait Op {
    type A
    def compute(a: A) : A
  }

  case object Count extends Op {
    type A = Int
    override def compute(a: Int): Int = a + 1
  }

  case object Exist extends Op {
    type A = Boolean
    override def compute(a: Boolean): Boolean = a
  }

  val ops = Seq(Count, Exist)

  def compute() = {
    val op0 = ops(0)
    val op1 = ops(1)
    buffer(0) = ops(0).compute(buffer(0).asInstanceOf[op0.A])
    buffer(1) = ops(0).compute(buffer(1).asInstanceOf[op0.A])
    buffer(2) = ops(1).compute(buffer(2).asInstanceOf[op1.A])
  }
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you attemted to achieve there, but are you aware of Shapeless' `HLists`?

Comment: Hi @AndreyTyukin. I've reworded the question to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve. I'm aware of Shapeless but I'd like to understand what is possible with raw Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your code can be simplified by making `Op[A]` extend `Any => A`:

```
trait Op[A] extends (Any => A) {
  def cast(a: Any) : A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
  def compute(a: A) : A
  def apply(a: Any): A = compute(cast(a))
}

case object Count extends Op[Int] {
  override def compute(a: Int): Int = a + 1
}

case object Exist extends Op[Boolean] {
  override def compute(a: Boolean): Boolean = a
}

object AbstractOp {

  val buffer: Array[Any] = Array(42, 21, true)
  val ops: Array[Op[_]] = Array(Count, Count, Exist)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (i <- 0 until buffer.size) {
      buffer(i) = ops(i)(buffer(i))
    }
    println(buffer.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
  }
}
```

Since it's `asInstanceOf` everywhere anyway, it does not make the code any less safe than what you had previously.

---

**Update**

If you cannot change the `Op` interface, then invoking `cast` and `compute` is a bit more cumbersome, but still possible:

```
trait Op[A] {
  def cast(a: Any) : A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
  def compute(a: A) : A
}

case object Count extends Op[Int] {
  override def compute(a: Int): Int = a + 1
}

case object Exist extends Op[Boolean] {
  override def compute(a: Boolean): Boolean = a
}

object AbstractOp {

  val buffer: Array[Any] = Array(42, 21, true)
  val ops: Array[Op[_]] = Array(Count, Count, Exist)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (i <- 0 until buffer.size) {
      buffer(i) = ops(i) match {
        case op: Op[t] => op.compute(op.cast(buffer(i)))
      }
    }
    println(buffer.mkString("[", ",", "]"))
  }
}
```

Note the `ops(i) match { case op: Opt[t] => ... }` part with a type-parameter in the pattern: this allows us to make sure that `cast` returns a `t` that is accepted by `compute`.

Answer (score 1):

As a more general solution than Andrey Tyukin's, you can define the method outside `Op`, so it works even if `Op` can't be modified:

```
def apply[A](op: Op[A], x: Any) = op.compute(op.cast(x))

buffer(0) = apply(ops(0), buffer(0))
```

Comment: Actually, you don't really need any additional methods at all. See update.

Comment: Yes, that's another option.